# MongoDb Upgrade from 2.6 to 3.0 Issue

Tags: mongodb, linux, ubuntu

For some reasons I cannot install MongoDb 3.0 version. What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like MongoDB provides a repo for Saucy: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/

So if you installed via Ubuntu-provided repository you have a few options:

- Remove the RPM and install [via binaries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/)
- Upgrade to Trusty
- Wait for Ubuntu to update its repo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's typically what I do to get Mongo installed on a brand new Ubuntu install. YMMV:

```
##Backup current sources list.
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sourcesBackup.list
```

Then open up vi to make a new sources list:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Copy and paste the default sources list (the distro's I use have a custom sources list, so you might not need to do this) but I also add the MongoDB repos.

```
##Generate Sources List 
##http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main 

##############################################################
##################### UNOFFICIAL  REPOS ######################
##############################################################

###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### MongoDB - http://www.mongodb.org/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen

#################################################################
```

Exit Vi:

```
#Now to exit vi type : to exit to vi shell, then type wq to write and quit.  :wq
```

Then type this in your command line:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen ##for v 2.2 or change for 2.4.12
```